# Invalid key hash.The key hash entered does not match any stored key hashes facebook flutter

Tags: facebook, firebase, flutter, dart, facebook-login

i have implemented Facebook login, submitted the key hash value in the facebook developers portal.but when i run my application it is displaying invalid key hash and its displaying a key hash value which is not the value i have added in the facebook developers page. can someone tell me whats's the problem please.